# Query to push to all users belonging to specific role

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

*This question is related to Parse.com*

I want to build a push query to push a notification from cloud code to all users belonging to 'Moderator' role.

I tried below code, it failed to push as "users" is a relation, not an object.

```
    var moderatorQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    moderatorQuery.equalTo("name", "Moderators");

    //  Push to devices belonging to these moderators
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.matchesKeyInQuery("installationOwner", "users", moderatorQuery);
```

Another way of doing this is by fetching the Moderator role object and using the relation.query() or by calling getUsers() on moderator object.

**But my requirement is to push to a query directly without fetching(get/find) any object.
How to build such a query ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first to get the role, then use it's user relation query as the query to match in the pushQuery, like this:

```
var moderatorQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
moderatorQuery.equalTo("name", "Moderators");
moderatorQuery.first().then(function(moderatorRole) {
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    var usersQuery = moderatorRole.relation("users").query();
    pushQuery.matchesQuery("installationOwner", usersQuery);
    // setup push, then send()
});
```

**EDIT** - Missed the last sentence of the question.  The short answer is that there's no way to query the "many" side of the relationship in a single query.

The longer answer is that it can be done with additional data.  You can make the query singular at the cost of keeping additional data up-to-date.

For example, you could keep an (a) isModerator bool on the `User`, or (b) more generally, a "roles" array of *pointers* (not a relation, because that's your root problem) on `User`, or (c) a separate table altogether that joins `Role` and `User` with singular pointers.

All of these ideas make the single-query easy (a) query `User` where isModerator == true, (b) query `User` where roles isEqual to moderator, (c) query TheJoinTable where role == moderator, include user and select user.

Doing this shifts the burden from the query to keeping the extra data up to date.  You could accomplish this pretty simply using `beforeSave` on either end of the Role-User relation (probably `Role`).

All that said, you should examine the added constraint of a single query very carefully and make sure its worth the extra trouble.

Comment: this is what I dont want.

Comment: Missed the last sentence.  See edit.  Its an unusual constraint... achievable but at a high cost compared to simply running a second query.  Can you add some explanation about why you want this?  Maybe there's a way around if we can understand the bigger objective.